# Configure custom auto heal rules in arm template (Is there a way to add multiple trigger conditions with multiple action type?)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to configure multiple auto heal rules in app services through arm template . but currently we can configure multiple trigger condition with single action type. Is there a way to configure pair trigger condition with action type in arm template? for example I want these two rules to configured to app service

1.Request count condition
Request Count: 10
Duration: 10min
Action: log an event

2. Status codes condition
   Request Count:  10
   status codes: 500
   Duration: 10min
   Action: Recycle

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Normally to work this out you set it up the resource directly then extract the ARM template and see what it looks like. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot configure multiple auto heal rules in app services. One app service just can have one auto heal rule. One  auto heal rule has one trigger and action. But one trigger can have some conditions. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-web?tabs=json) and [here](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/09/10/Announcing-the-New-Auto-Healing-Experience-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html)